# Google Chrome: how to manage autofill email address / phone number?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

Google Chrome autofills email address / phone number.

However, in "Autofill => Addresses and more" I see no saved email address / phone number:
[image]

I am confused. Where is the autofilled email address / phone number stored? How to change it?

Comment: It adds/fills both together, or just field by field? The latter is called Autofill form data, and it's not available to see in the settings. You can clear them all by going to Settings>Clear browsing data and check only "Autofill form data" (you'll see there are "addresses" and then "suggestions."

Comment: Field by field. It is very unexpected that Autofill form data is not available to see in the settings. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't really know why Google is doing it this way. But it kinda makes sense that you don't want a treasure trove of personal information all in one place.

Comment: If I go "Clear browsing data => check only Autofill form data", then it will clear (I guess) all Autofill form data. However, I don't need to clear all Autofill form data. Instead I need to remove / change specific entries in Autofill form data.

Comment: See (the 2nd part of) my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see isn't the **Addresses** type of autofill, but the **Suggestions** autofill. Those entries cannot be reviewed/modified.

To delete all of those:

1. Click on the Kebab (3 dots) menu and go to **Settings**
2. Under the ***Privacy and security*** section, click on **Clear browsing data** and go to the **Advanced** tab
3. Choose ***All Time*** from the Time range, and uncheck all items in the list leaving only **Autofill form data** checked
4. Then click on **Clear data**
   [image]

---

To delete only specific entries showing up as suggestions:

1. Click in the field/input box those suggestions are showing up in
2. When the list of suggestions shows up, use the down arrow key to highlight the auto-fill entry you want to delete
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on the keyboard (this works on most Windows device. It's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> on a Chromebook, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete (backspace)</kbd> on a Mac.)

Comment: Re: "Those entries cannot be reviewed/modified": do you know whether Google Chrome developers are aware of that? Do they plan to fix it?

Comment: I'm not aware. But to be honest, what's the need? Unlike addresses which fill in all relevant fields in the page, these entries are only per field, so you can remove/delete as I showed, and simply type in something new to add. (So what would you need to "modify"?)

Comment: As I understand one can delete all autofill form data at once. However, what if one has many (e.g. hundreds or thousands) entries in the autofill form data, and needs to _modify or delete some entries_ in the autofill form data? I.e. w/o deleting all autofill form data at once. For example, the email address is mistyped, some search queries are not relevant any longer, etc.

Comment: I'd like to add entries, but when I type in something new, the new entry is no longer getting saved...